# How to increase `akka.http.server.parsing.max-method-length` in Akka HTTP?

Tags: scala, websocket, akka-http

How to fix the increase max method length in Akka HTTP. I am getting the below issue in web socket connection service.

```
Illegal request, responding with status '400 Bad Request': Unsupported
 HTTP method: HTTP method too long (started with '￼ﾒ﾿vN'). Increase 
`akka.http.server.parsing.max-method-length` to support HTTP methods with more characters.
```

I have added the **akka.http.server.parsing.max-method-length** in **application.conf**.
After adding the **max-method-length** also am getting the same issue and my .conf file is:

```
    app {
  interface = "0.0.0.0"
  port = 7000
}

# Cors allowed origin configuration
# ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
cors {
 allowed-origin = "http://127.0.0.1"
}


akka {
  http {
    server.parsing.illegal-header-warnings = off
    client.parsing.illegal-header-warnings = off
  }
}
akka.http.server.parsing.max-method-length =500
```

Comment: I can't find any documentation on the `max-method-length` but it appears to be referring to the http request method (e.g. 'GET', 'POST', 'PUT', ...).  Why would you want to change the default value of 16 to 500?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods

Answer (score 5):

I was getting the same error and also had no success changing the max-method-length conf value.

The problem in my case was that my request URL was mistakenly using https instead of http. The above mentioned error stopped occurring after changing my request to http://

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when *intentionally* running an app in dev mode on HTTPs port with `sbt "run -Dhttps.port=9443 -Dhttp.port=disabled"`

Turned out, Play was trying to generate keys for a self-sighed certificate in `./conf/generated.keystore` (`INFO play.core.server.ssl.FakeKeyStore "Generating HTTPS key pair in %appdir%/conf/generated.keystore`) and was silently failing to do so as there was no `./conf` folder.

**Solution**: create `conf` folder so Play can create `generated.keystore` file, or provide a proper path with `play.server.https.keyStore.path`.
See more here: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.7.x/ConfiguringHttps

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error because of not adding header `Content-Length` into `POST` request with parameters in the body and header `Content-Type` having value `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. So after adding the header `Content-Length` with correct length the request started to work successfully.

Answer (score -1):

I came across the same error when I access https with wrong port.

For example I have play running http://localhost:9000

when I enable the https port on 9443

I visit https://localhost:9000 will get the same error message.

change to https://localhost:9443 will resolve the issue.